# Using a bottle rinser with 500ml PET bottles

Tags: cleaning, bottles

just a quick question regarding the use of bottle rinsers to clean out 500ml PET bottles.

I'm looking at this bottle rinser here: http://www.the-home-brew-shop.co.uk/acatalog/Bottle-Rinser-AVVINATORE.html#a0212183

I'm planning on getting these PET bottles: http://www.the-home-brew-shop.co.uk/acatalog/Coopers_Pet_Bottles_Ox-Bar_24_x_500ml.html#a786381

The other bottle rinser they sell, which looks very similar, says PET bottles are too large, I was hoping one of you have had experience with bottle rinsers and PET bottles, so could potentially guide me in the right direction towards one that will work properly.

Also if you have any experience with the bottles (good or bad, would be nice to know before I place an order for 96 of them (4 x 24).

Thanks,
Carl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a very similar pump sprayer to sanitize bottles as large as 1.75L wine bottles, so those 500mL bottles shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same bottle rinser as well as those bottles. The neck is indeed too large and you will not be able to directly position the bottle over the rinser as you would a 12 oz glass bottle.

However, you will still be able to use these two items together, it is just a bit less convenient. You will need to angle the neck slightly so that the lip of the bottle hits the first abutment on the pump. I've attached a picture of where this is. It is tricky because if you do not keep the bottle at an angle, the whole neck of the pump will annoyingly slide into the bottle.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can fit the appropriate sized food grade stainless steel washer over the collar at the position indicated in the above picture and you should have no problems washing most sized bottles, you need to make sure the inside diameter of the washer is big enough to slip over the first part of the rinser but not so big it slips all the way down, I hope this helps